# How can I prevent discord app from prompting about audio devices?

Tags: discord

I don't use headphones/microphone on discord, so far and am unlikely to start. With the windows discord app, when I change audio devices, discord prompts me to ask if I want to change audio devices. How can I get it to stop doing this? I've set input and output audio devices to default.

Answer (score 4):

You can click the "Don't show me this again" in the prompt.

Comment: I don't know why this answer has been voted down so much, but it is the correct solution to this question. Just click on the blue link when this prompt appears again and Discord won't ask you again.

Comment: @StanE there is no such option?

Comment: Edit: there is, I guess most people (including me) don't see this option exist because it's not a checkbox, it's a link.

Comment: This option does exist but it doesn't work. I have been checking this box for over a year and it still happens... Every. Single. Time....

Comment: @Jeremy that sounds like a bug. have you contacted discord support about it?

Comment: Wrong - there is no checkbox.

Comment: @Soheil I don't know how it is now, but that option definitely existed when I made that answer.
But it wasn't a checkbox

Answer (score 1):

I speculate that this is a problem with HDMI and your screen being locked/unlocked. It happens to me regularly with my multi-monitor, multi-videocard setup.

**Even if you don't have audio built into your monitor**, Windows often assumes you do. My machine also will occasionally switch to the non-existent HDMI audio out, in discord or elsewhere. And then I can't hear anyone until I manually switch back to the actual audio input.

So what is probably happening is that your monitor goes into power-saving mode, then when you become active again it detects the HDMI turning on as a "new audio device" (even if it doesn't support audio) and pops up that alert.

The same can happen with other display types that support audio, like DisplayPort.

Comment: I think it's happening when I switch between headphones and the builtin speaker. But, I really want to know  how to get it to stop asking.

Comment: @Kaz Vorpal That's an explanation why it happens, but not how to solve it. AntonV has given the correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

Go to the old Control Panel, click Hardware and Sound, and click Sound. In the list find the device that Discord keeps trying to switch to, such as the speakers in your monitors, and right-click and select disable for each.

I can confirm that for me clicking "Don't show me this again" in the prompt did not stop Discord from continuing to ask whether to switch to my monitor speakers, but the above certainly worked.

Answer (score -1):

There is no way to disable that prompt as of now. This shows how anti-privacy Discord is as a product. They really want to listen in on what you have to say all the time.

Comment: That's a serious allegation, and would indicate a breach of many countries' data protection and surveillance laws. It would also signal the end of Discord, as the company would collapse once proof is provided and national and supra-national authorities pile in with criminal prosecutions and massive civil cases. Do you have evidence of this? For example, Wireshark comms logs?